# Delete all previous versions of file in git repo

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a single file in a git repo and it contains sensitive information.  I've removed this information in the latest commit.  Now I want to delete all previous versions of this file from the git repository.  How can this be done?

I believe it can be done with git-filter-branch but I haven't come across an example I can wrap my head around yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting the git documentation:

> Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information
>   or copyright violation) from all commits:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm filename" HEAD
> ```
>
> However, if the file is absent from the tree of some commit, a simple
>   rm filename will fail for that tree and commit. Thus you may instead
>   want to use `rm -f filename` as the script.

So you want to run `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f filename" HEAD` to erase all history of that file

Comment: That was easy!  I just added and committed the latest version of the file after deleting its history from the repository. Thanks.

Comment: @phelpsw, make sure to change the password(s) from that file. It is still possible that they were compromised...